# How to align two div horizontally and vertically in middle of page with header and footer?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am designing a new page using Bootstrap 4. There are 4 elements in the page header, footer and two content boxes(divs). Header and footer will remain at top and bottom respectively (using default bootstrap classes for them) but i want both content boxes should appear in middle of the page both horizontally and vertically regardless of the screen size. One content box beneath the another with space between them. You can refer attached picture for same.

I have tried using flex class of bootstrap but it didn't work out much.[image]

Comment: Can you share the code of what have you tried?

Comment: See similar solution provided here [Put two divs next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509612/how-can-i-put-two-divs-next-to-each-other-and-have-it-take-up-the-whole-width-of/56510024#56510024)

Comment: @NdifrekeEkim Well putting two divs next to each other is easy. I have said one div beneath another div and both should remain in centre regardless of screen size.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of approaches to get this solution. That's a simple one:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="container-fluid">HEADER</header>

        <main>
            <div class="center">
                <div id="container-1" class="">DIV 1</div>
                <div id="container-2" class="">DIV 2</div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer class="container-fluid">FOOTER</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    background-color: red;
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 60px; /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}

footer {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}

#container-1 {
    padding: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#container-2 {
    padding: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.center {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Result**

[Divs centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Nft.png)